# MySQL query show the result out of range

Tags: mysqli

I have the following mysqli query in my search.php file with ajax.

```
SELECT demand2.* FROM demand2 
WHERE ddate >= '$dto' AND ddate >= '$dfrom' AND !(mach='--' OR mach='-' OR mach='' OR mach='----' OR mach='-----' OR mach='---');
```

field `ddate` is datatype of **varchar2**

as I entered Date From 01-01-2019 and Date To 30-01-2019, it shows the result with previous date like 29-12-2019.

So I can't find the solution to get result within specified range. Please Help.

Comment: show the raw query you are executing.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for between? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: SELECT demand2.*, FROM demand2 WHERE ddate >= '$dto' AND ddate >= '$dfrom';

Comment: @rypskar... I have used BETWEEN but not works. Is my datatype is ok for ddate field as varchar2...?

Comment: Field need to be date if you want to use between. If you have it as varchar2 you will use alphabetical compare, so 1-12-2019 will be before 30-1-2019. The only way to compare dates if not using a date field is to store it as ISO string, 2019-01-31

Answer (score 0):

Just as rypskar said, your type of field should be date.

If you don't want to change the datatype of the fiels, then you have to convert the string to date with STR_TO_DATE(ddate, '%d-%m-%Y'). But this is not recommended, as it will cause performance degradation on larger tables.

So your query would be like that (not tested!):

```
SELECT demand2.* FROM demand2 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(ddate, '%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('$dto', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(ddate, '%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('$dfrom', '%d-%m-%Y') AND !(mach='--' OR mach='-' OR mach='' OR    mach='----' OR mach='-----' OR mach='---');
```

If you want to keep the varchar type of field and not make any runtime conversions, then you have to change the format to Y-m-d, so the comparison with character set will work the same as a date comparison.

Right now, you are getting the result of 29-12-2019 because 29 is between 1 and 30.

Comment: Thanks I will try STR_TO_DATE().

Comment: Okay. As I can see that you are a new contributor, I would like to remind you to accept the answer if it solves your problem ;)

Comment: Okay, STR_TO_DATE not solved the problem but the main thing you and rypskar said ---- the field must be DATE of type. So One thing I have learnt that before you feed the data ensure about the datatypes used in database engine. Thanks to both rypskar and papa_zulu.